# issues with Anchor Links, have to click twice on links in Mobile Nav Menu on Mobile Device with Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I have created a mobile Navigation and have some links in it that reference anchor tags. Everything works fine on a desktop. But when I open the [site](http://mobile-responsive-single-page.bitballoon.com/) on a **Mobile device with Chrome**, when you open the navigation menu, and you click on one of the links for example, **ABOUT**, the anchor tag works fine (the first time). but if you click on the navigation menu again and try to click any other link (**ABOUT, WORK, or CONTACT**), then it will take you to the top of page (which is not where it should take you) as if you clicked on a link with an `href="#"`. Now if you try a third time, the links work again.

So it works when you click a link an odd number of times, but not when you click it an even number of times.

I think it has something to do with when you click on the **ABOUT** link the first time, you get directed to: `http://mobile-responsive-single-page.bitballoon.com/#about`

site: http://mobile-responsive-single-page.bitballoon.com/

Not sure.

Im not sure how to fix this, but like i said, I only receive the error with a chrome browser on a mobile device. Safari works fine Mobile.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:**

Soo after a ton of manual testing, I found that the Links only work if they have been clicked on before.

Example:

You go to site: http://mobile-responsive-single-page.bitballoon.com/
You open the slide Navigation
You click on the **ABOUT** link, but nothing will happen
You open the slide Navigation again, but now your URL is:
`http://mobile-responsive-single-page.bitballoon.com/#aboutMe`
You now click on the **ABOUT** link, and this time, it will take you to the anchor.

I have no `:hover` on the element, there is an `:active` on it, but i removed it and was still receiving the same issue when i tested it.

Any Ideas?

Thanks All!!!

Comment: @MaihanNijat have you tried to repetitively click on different links in the mobile nav on a Mobile Device with chrome (im using an iphone)? not the Chrome mobile emulator.

Comment: I tested with responsive test websites. And clicked many times on different links.

Comment: not sure then... Its still not working properly for my iPhone with Chrome.

Comment: What happens when you click it once? Does it trigger the hover state?

Comment: @RyanLittle, I removed the hover state on these elements. theres an `:active` state though.

Comment: And what happens if you remove the `:active` state?

Comment: still not working, and now the nav sometimes wont open after a link is clicked.